# Approve / reject list item using workflow

Tags: workflow, web-services

I have an approve reject workflow attached to one of the document library. Is there any way I can "approve" or "reject" the item using a built in websevice, just like we approve/reject through the workflow form?

Comment: Looks like there is no way to interact with "SharePoint 2010 style workflows" using REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did that using ***Workflow.asmx***'s ***AlterToDo***.
Basically closing the ***Task*** associated with the workflow completes the workflow. I was able to do that using Workflow.asmx but updating ***Tasks List*** directly with REST api will also do the same.

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814828/approve-a-sharepoint-workflow-task-using-sharepoint-web-services-object-model) thread, setting "TaskStatus" as "Approved" is mandatory to set the workflow completed.